# building xmlp library on windows

Tags: xml, d

I'm currently trying to build the xmlp library for d2 on windows, but I keep getting the following error(I'm building it using the git bash):

```
$ ./build2.sh
D:/__dev/D/dmd2/windows/bin/dmd -g -ofTestXmlConf inrange/recode.d inrange/instring.d inrange/instream.d xmlp/input.d xmlp/format.
d xmlp/compatible.d xmlp/xmlrules.d xmlp/except.d xmlp/xmldom.d xmlp/pieceparser.d xmlp/delegater.d D:/__dev/D/dmd2/src/phobos/std
/ctype.d D:/__dev/D/dmd2/src/phobos/std/utf.d D:/__dev/D/dmd2/src/phobos/std/file.d XmlConf.d
xmlp\pieceparser.d(123): function declaration without return type. (Note that constructors are always named 'this')
xmlp\pieceparser.d(123): no identifier for declarator HashSet(DOMString)
xmlp\pieceparser.d(123): semicolon expected following function declaration
xmlp\pieceparser.d(123): no identifier for declarator pending
```

My build2.sh looks like the following:

```
path=D:/__dev/D/dmd2
plib=${path}/src/phobos/
xp=xmlp/
dcomp2=${path}/windows/bin/dmd
inr=inrange/

src="${inr}recode.d ${inr}instring.d ${inr}instream.d ${xp}input.d ${xp}format.d ${xp}compatible.d ${xp}xmlrules.d ${xp}except.d ${xp}xmldom.d ${xp}pieceparser.d ${xp}delegater.d"  

psrc="${plib}std/ctype.d ${plib}std/utf.d ${plib}std/file.d"  

makeit "${dcomp2} -g -ofTestXmlConf ${src} ${psrc} XmlConf.d"
makeit "${dcomp2} -g -ofTestBooks ${src} ${psrc} ElementHandler.d "
makeit "${dcomp2} -release -ofRelXmlConf ${src} ${psrc} XmlConf.d"
makeit "${dcomp2} -release -ofRelBooks ${src} ${psrc} ElementHandler.d "
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what the issue is, but it looks like it can't find the type needed or something. One solution might be to checkout revision 12, which was before the change of that line.

Update:

Development moved to the std folder.

http://www.dsource.org/projects/xmlp/browser/trunk/std

The current revision requires the work done in hash

http://www.dsource.org/projects/xmlp/browser/trunk/hash

Though you can change the two places it is used to use the built in hashtable.

Comment: Ok, i've changed that one line to the one of revision 12, but it still seems to get compiling errors. Now though on files and folder that don't seem to exist i.e. sxml and std\xml\array.d

Comment: @creatio, I recommended revision 12 because that is what I have been using and haven't had issue.